# Is it correct to say semi-promise?

Tags: phrases, vocabulary, writing-style, synonyms

I want to say, someone *sort of* promised to do something, yet it was not a full promise:

> She had a semi-promise from his employer to get a raise this year.

Is *semi-promise* correct in this sense? What are the alternatives?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the comments. I have also come up with *provisional promise*:

> Her boss has made a provisional promise to finally give her a raise.

Comment: Promises either are or are not.

Comment: Maybe "half-hearted promise", but the recipient would probably have needed to sense at the time that it wasn't genuine or likely to happen.

Comment: No, *semi-promise* is neither a word not a sensible concept. If it isn't a promise, forget the word *promise*, chose a less intensive, non-committal word or expression.

Answer (score 2):

- tentative promise
- conditional promise
- non-binding pledge

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think another alternative is "provisional promise".

Answer (score 1):

The term is *half-promise* (noun and verb).

Answer (score 1):

I think the semi-promise just means "I will try to".  I wouldn't want my employer semi-promising me anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *semi-promise* is proper but just less used:

> As a result, the Peking Government felt constrained to ask for more
>   than it had been promised at Washington. It asked, among other things,
>   for complete and immediate tariff autonomy. It got nothing except an
>   unofficial **semi-promise** of tariff autonomy in 1929.-Aspects of British foreign policy, by Sir Arthur ... . Willert, Arthur, Sir, 1882

Contemporary:

- [One simple example is the too-common line in a fundraising message that makes a **semi-promise** of an award for participation](http://www.thenonprofittimes.com/news-articles/creative-masterclass/)
- [This was not authoritative enough to be held out as an incentive to the soldiers and so probably cut little or no figure in the results, but Virginia did not forget the **semi-promise**.](http://www.countyhistory.com/history/040.htm)

Comment: Something seems to be not quite right with the years in the first citation. A text from 1882 shouldn't really be talking about events that took place in 1929.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet, you are confusing auctorial information with publication.  Often the dates of birth death and floruit are included after the title

Comment: Ah, I see—1882 is his birth year, just written in a somewhat non-standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that we are all prone on 'semi-promising'

Useful expressions are:

- I' m not sure but I'll do my best to...
- I can not guarantee but I think I will be able to...
- I will do every effort to ..., but I am not sure I will be able to...

As for [semi-promise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%20semi-promise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,semi%20-%20promise;,c0), Ngram reveals some evidence of usage especially in the past, but I would definitely  use alternative expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> She had *a glimpse of hope* from her boss that she might get a raise this year.
>
> Her boss gave her *a glimpse of hope* that she might get a raise this year.

Answer (score 0):

To add to existing answers, I have seen **semi-promise** used, but very occasionally. I would say **half-promise** is slightly more popular and commonly used. Since there have been examples provided in other answers for "semi-promise" but not "half-promise", there is one from [the New Zealand parliamentary debates from the 1980s](https://books.google.com/books?id=b3crAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA4609#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> The Bill represents a broken **half-promise**—"nudge, nudge, wink, wink"—by the Leader of the Opposition in Timaru only a short time ago.